# What data gets submitted by a textarea?

Tags: php, html, textarea

When you submit a textarea, how is it submitted? How would I access each row of data in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want an array of items:

```
$arr=explode("\n", $_POST[text_area_name]);
```

then access them

```
foreach($arr as $item){
    print $item;
}
```

Comment: Also, how would I insert each entry into a MySQL database, with a unique ID from an array, sequentially?

Comment: just replace the `print $item;` with your sql insert statement. as long as you set up your table to have an auto incrementing column, it will be given its own unique id when you insert it

Comment: you can do anything you want with `$item`: update, select, insert, delete.  `$item` is a string with a value of whatever was on that line of the text area. you can do anything with it that you can do with any other string.

Answer (score 1):

It's a text blob. You have to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You access the whole string of text.

For example, with POST:

```
$str = $_POST['nameoftextarea'];
$lineArray = explode("\n", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is still an issue, but some operating systems send not just newlines `\n` they also send carriage returns `\r`, so I've used `preg_split()` for this to account for the variability. For example:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
<textarea name="myMultiline">foo
bar
baz</textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['myMultiline'])) {
    $multiline_as_array = preg_split("/[\n\r]+/", $_POST['myMultiline']);
    print_r($multiline_as_array);
}
?>
```